# How to mount wsl folder path as volume in pod.yaml

Tags: docker, kubernetes, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-desktop

I have installed Ubuntu as WSL, and I am creating pod in Ubuntu (WSL) with WSL folder as volume.
The folder is there in WSL Ubuntu, but it is giving an error while mounting sating it is not a directory.

I am mounting as HostPath and the type is Directory.

How can I avoid this error message?

Answer (score 0):

This seems similar to [`docker/for-win` issue 9823](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/9823), with the exact error message:

> If, using the WSL2 backend, I mount a directory at a local path, I can then at a later point mount a file from the same path.

But:

```bash
/tmp/docker-repro$ mkdir foo
/tmp/docker-repro$ docker run --rm -v /tmp/docker-repro/foo:/foo ubuntu ls -la foo 
# works
```

Later on:

```bash
/tmp/docker-repro$ rm -rf foo/
/tmp/docker-repro$ touch foo  # <=== now mount a file, not a folder, should work
/tmp/docker-repro$docker run --rm -v /tmp/docker-repro/foo:/foo ubuntu ls -la foo
docker: Error response from daemon: not a directory.
```

If that is not your case, you also have [`docker/compose-cli` issue 1795](https://github.com/docker/compose-cli/issues/1795#issuecomment-936509371), with a `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
app:
  image: invoiceninja/invoiceninja:5
  container_name: InvoiceNinja5
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - ./config/hosts:/etc/hosts:ro
    - ./docker/app/public/:/var/www/app/public/:rw,delegated
    - ./docker/app/storage/:/var/www/app/storage/:rw,delegated
```

Resulting in:

```
Cannot start service app: failed to create shim: 
OCI runtime create failed: 
container_linux.go:380: starting container process 
caused: process_linux.go:545: container init 
caused: rootfs_linux.go:76: mounting "/data/compose/8/config/hosts" to rootfs at "/etc/hosts" 
caused: mount through procfd: not a directory: unknown: 
Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? 
Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
```

With the root cause being:

> You're bind-mounting `./config/hosts` from the host into the container; if `/data/compose/8/` is your compose project directory, and there's no file named `config/hosts`, then docker will assume you're trying to bind-mount a directory, and create one.
>
> So you either need to remove that bind-mount from your compose file, or If the intent is to provide a custom `/etc/hosts` for your container, then you need to create that file before running the compose file.

So it depends on how you are running your Docker container and which directives you used to do your mount.